# Efficiently finding the ultimate parent in multi-level one-to-many tables

Tags: postgresql, database-design

Let's say I have a database with multi-level one-to-many tables (a contrived example):

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE properties (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  user_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES users(id)
);

CREATE TABLE rooms (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  property_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES properties(id)
)

CREATE TABLE rates (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  price INTEGER NOT NULL,
  room_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES rooms(id)
)
```

Let's say a user wants to update the `price` in `rates` table but I want to make sure that he is allowed to do so - i.e. the `rate` belongs to a `room` that itself belongs to a `property` that the user owns.

What would be the best/efficient way to do so? Is there a way to add a "deduced" `user_id` column to the `rates` table that is automatically populated as the rows are added to the `rates` table so later I can use it in a query like:

```
UPDATE rates SET price=100 WHERE (id=30) AND (user_id=1)`
```

Comment: After a few tests, it looks like that the most efficient way to ensure `user` owns a `rooms` or `rates` row, is to have an additional `user_id` in each of those tables and check it during each request; rather than trying to traverse the parent chain in each request.

Comment: My guess is that you have multiple queries to the DB during "traversing" -- back and forth between app and the DB -- which takes time. Also keep in mind that testing efficiency (speed) on small data sets is misleading because everything is in memory, so CPU cycles are  the only resource in play.

Answer (score 2):

I simplified a bit by allowing only one price for a given room in the `rates` table.

```sql
CREATE TABLE users (
  user_id INTEGER NOT NULL
, CONSTRAINT pk_users PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
);

CREATE TABLE properties (
  property_id INTEGER NOT NULL
, user_id     INTEGER NOT NULL
, CONSTRAINT pk_prop PRIMARY KEY (property_id)
, CONSTRAINT fk1_prop FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
                 REFERENCES users (user_id)
);

CREATE TABLE rooms (
  room_id     INTEGER NOT NULL
, property_id INTEGER NOT NULL
, CONSTRAINT pk_rooms PRIMARY KEY (room_id)
, CONSTRAINT fk1_rooms FOREIGN KEY (property_id)
             REFERENCES properties (property_id)
);

CREATE TABLE rates (
  room_id INTEGER NOT NULL
, price   INTEGER NOT NULL
, CONSTRAINT pk_rates PRIMARY KEY (room_id)
, CONSTRAINT fk1_rates FOREIGN KEY (room_id)
                  REFERENCES rooms (room_id)
);
```

Some data to test

```sql
INSERT INTO users (user_id)
VALUES (1), (2), (3) ;

INSERT INTO properties (property_id, user_id)
VALUES
(11, 1), (12, 1), (13, 1),
(21, 2), (22, 2),
(31, 3) ;

INSERT INTO rooms (room_id, property_id)
VALUES
(1101,11), (1102,11),
(1201,12), (1202,12),
(1301,13), (1302,13),
(2101,21), (2102,21),
(2201,22), (2202,22), (2203,22),
(3101,31), (3102,31), (3103,31) ;

INSERT INTO rates (room_id, price)
VALUES
(1101,110), (1102,110),
(1201,120), (1202,120),
(1301,130), (1302,130),
(2101,210), (2102,210),
(2201,220), (2202,220), (2203,220),
(3101,310), (3102,310), (3103,310) ;
```

Update price for `room_id = 2102` to 100, if and only if it belongs to `user_id = 2`.

```sql
UPDATE rates      AS t SET price = 100
  FROM rooms      AS r
  JOIN properties AS p ON p.property_id = r.property_id
  JOIN users      AS u ON u.user_id     = p.user_id
 WHERE t.room_id = r.room_id
   AND r.room_id = 2102
   AND u.user_id = 2
;
```

---

[image: user_property_room_rate]

Note that all joins are on PKs, so this is fast. Also there are no multiple trips to the app and back.

[Try it on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=67c0a48da539e19b3a11465787e9085e) or [visualise the `explain`](https://explain.depesz.com/s/HtUY)!

Comment: Thanks. I'll run some tests on a bigger dataset. One thing that I noticed though, is by having a `user_id` column for each table, my queries are much shorter and easier to debug by removing most of the joins, but obviously at the expense of duplicating `user_id` column throughout all the tables.

Comment: @user31208 Nothing wrong with propagating `user_id`, just make sure that PK (or AK) is then for property: `{user_id, user_property_no}`, for room: `{user_id, user_property_no, property_room_no}` with proper FKs, etc.